# Screen Scrape Or Crawl Dropdown Fields with all permutation from another site

Tags: .net, web-crawler

First i need to ask whats the difference between crawler and screen scraping.
secondly i want to crawl or screen **scrape** drop down fields with different permutations so that i can get that data in my own database.e.g there is a categories drop down when i select a category then its related  subcategory is populated when i select its subcategory then its related subcategory is populated and so on with different combinations.All i want is that categories that comes with different permutations stores  in my Database.
I will be using C#.net

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks.
Waqar Iqbal.

Answer (score 0):

Crawling - Collecting **information about** web pages themselves, and determining their structure and value.

Screen Scraping - Collecting **content within** a webpage and storing / using the content.

This can all be accomplished using the [.NET `WebBrowser` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) and it's internal functions (which you would gather information from it's `HtmlElement`'s)

Comment: no i think it would need a crawler cuz i need to get data in dropdown from another site.Any idea working with crawler in getting dropdown items.

Comment: @user - A crawler does not do that - it won't get information from the drop down. That is what a content scraper does. You can create crawling functionality to *get to* another site however. Again, all possible within the `WebBrowser`.

Comment: thanks for ur response..hmmm so i dun have to write crawler and scraper..
do u have any example related to my scenario??

Comment: @user - Update your question with a bit more of a process of what you're wanting to do, and i will try give an example. It's just too generic right now.

Comment: Well, it's a bit less generic, but you'd use the `WebBrowser` to get the element with a certain attribute from the Html (`HtmlElement` in fact) and pull out the `InnerHtml` from those elements and parse them out (using the `<li>'s`). It really does depend on how generic you are wanting to go.

Comment: ok i will try and figure out with ur suggestions.thanks its been so nice of u cheers :)